# How to automate docker pull from azurecr.io?

Tags: azure, docker

I am currently working on a workstation that needs to run the most recent version of a given docker container hosted on azurecr. What I manually do is:

1. az login, which makes me use a web browser to authenticate
2. docker pull my_registry.azurecr.io/my_image:latest
3. docker run ... my_registry.azurecr.io/my_image:latest

I can automate via cron or whatever the docker pull and docker run  (steps 2 and 3) but I am unable to automate step 1. Do you know of any approach to accomplish this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- [create Service Principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli#password-based-authentication)

  ```
  # Create a service principal with required parameter
  az ad sp create-for-rbac --scopes /subscriptions/mySubscriptionID
  ```
- [add ACR Pull permission for this Principal for your registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-service-principal#use-an-existing-service-principal)

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  # Modify for your environment. The ACR_NAME is the name of your Azure Container
  # Registry, and the SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_ID is the service principal's 'appId' or
  # one of its 'servicePrincipalNames' values.
  ACR_NAME=$containerRegistry
  SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_ID=$servicePrincipal

  # Populate value required for subsequent command args
  ACR_REGISTRY_ID=$(az acr show --name $ACR_NAME --query id --output tsv)

  # Assign the desired role to the service principal. Modify the '--role' argument
  # value as desired:
  # acrpull:     pull only
  # acrpush:     push and pull
  # owner:       push, pull, and assign roles
  az role assignment create --assignee $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_ID --scope 
  $ACR_REGISTRY_ID --role acrpull
  ```
- [and then use this Principal to login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli#sign-in-with-a-service-principal)

  ```
  az login --service-principal -u <app-id> -p <password-or-cert> --tenant <tenant>
  ```

In this way you avoid interactive login and you should be able to run it in cron.

Comment: @malfonsoarquimea could you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful?